# Install4j - Change the text of the "Next" button to "Install"

Tags: java, install4j

In install4j, how can I change the text of the "Next" button to "Install" in the screen just before the Installation screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "Pre-activation script" property of the screen call

```
context.getWizardContext().setNextButtonText("Install");
```